# Laravel 5.8 - Trying to build a Model Where by pulling information from database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

So I have a query string saved in a Database, (Filters Table)

[image]

So when I pull this using its corresponding model like below and put it in the where() of another model (Devices Table) I am trying build my query on I get errors,

[image]

This is what I am mainly getting,

If i copy the plain text from the database and put it straight into the where() it works fine, so I think there must be something upsettings it when it's been pulled?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text. Images of code are really hard to work with.

Comment: You're going to have to parse out your av_status, because it's passing in `['category', '=', 'Server]` as a string.

Comment: @Jerodev sorry, I will do, new to this :D

Answer (score 0):

First issue:

Data stored in database doesn't look right.

`[category', '=', 'Server]` should probably be `['category', '=', 'Server']`

Second issue:

`Model::where(['category', '=', 'Server'])->get()` isn't proper syntax. You will throw a SQLSTATE 42S22 with that.

What you need is:

`Model::where('category', '=' ,'Server')->get();`

To do that, you can probably just split the string (Return from the database is likely string), then use the parts of the split to fill the `where()`.

```php
$arr = explode(', ', $AVMatchData);
$notDetected = Device::where($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2])->first();
```

Third [albeit nitpicky] issue:

Models should have a capital, going by PSRs.

Comment: Hello, Sorry the first issue was me messing around trying to work out what was going on, I am going to implement what you have suggested and I have also changed all models starting with a capital  :), I will let you know how it goes, thanks for your time and effort.